# What is the difference between beta and alpha API's?

Tags: php, api, google-api, alpha, beta

What is the difference between beta and alpha API's?  I've seen these two versions offered on Google's Developers API website for PHP:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/downloads

Comment: its nothing particular to any api or google, its just what we like to call various releases of software: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beta and alpha releases of software, or APIs, is a common term in development. They are both for products still under development. A product is first released for alpha testing, then bugs are reported and fixed, and an improved beta version is released. After that has been tested, the product is ready for an official release. So you can expect to find more bugs and instability in alpha than beta.

For those APIs you linked to, you don't have a choice between beta and alpha. There is only one option for each different library.

Comment: Definitely appreciate this!